# Create instance of view controller with correct constructor

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller, constructor, xamarin.ios

In the tutorial [Use Split View to Show two Controllers](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/split_view/use_split_view_to_show_two_controllers/) you create an instance of a view controller in this way:

```
masterView = new MasterViewController ();
```

Therefore you need a constructor like this:

```
public MasterViewController () : base()
```

Here my problem currently is that my `MasterViewController` isn't loaded. If I run the app an empty table is shown but mine should have some customization and data in it.

Now I'm using a custom cell. In the tutorial [Part 2 - Populating a Table with Data](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_2_-_populating_a_table_with_data/) it is clearly stated:

> Be aware, when using the new reuse pattern with a custom cell class,
>   you need to implement the constructor that takes an IntPtr, as shown
>   in the snippet below, otherwise Objective-C won't be able to construct
>   an instance of the cell class

```
public MasterViewController (IntPtr ptr) : base (ptr)
```

If I change my constructor to this I get

```
The type MasterViewController does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.
```

when I try to instantiate the view controller.

How can I instantiate a view controller with correct constructor?

Comment: what is MasterViewController?  What does it inherit from?

Comment: *MasterViewController* inherits from `UITableViewController`.

Comment: You need to post more code.  The stuff about using Custom Cells has nothing to with how you instantiate your TableViewController.

Comment: @Jason: The main question is: How can I instantiate a view controller? You can use Storyboard and the constructor method shown above. But with both I had problems. The next question is: When I use the constructor method (needed for custom table cell) what `IntPtr` do I use? Or does the constructor looks different? I have a sample project where you can play http://cdn.vanillaforums.com/xamarin.vanillaforums.com/FileUpload/20/496cb45e18e23ee7d5079a30cf35c8.zip

Comment: both of your TableViewControllers are empty classes - you have to assign a TableViewSource in order to display any data.  I don't see any problem with how you are instantiating them

Comment: You're right. I experimented with it but I don't have the project in this form anymore. It was the basis for my work. If you'd like I could implement a source again with a custom table view cell. Than you'd need the `IntPtr`.

Comment: The comment in the docs about the IntPtr constructor ONLY applies to the custom cell class, not the TableViewController.  It also ONLY applies when using the newer reuse pattern.  I would suggest getting your code working with one of the built-in cell types first, then try adding a custom cell.

Comment: @Jason: Is there another way for instantiating a view controller in code with a `IntPtr` in the constructor than using `storyboard.InstantiateViewController`? If I use `new MasterViewController ()` only then the controls on the view are not instantiated. This is similar to the chapter [Types and Interface Builder](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/under_the_hood/api_design/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I'm using the following pattern for the constructor of my view controllers:

```
public MasterViewController () : base()
{
    initialize();
}

public MasterViewController (IntPtr ptr) : base (ptr)
{
    initialize();
}

private initialize()
{
    // do your initialization here
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can instantiate things from storyboard as well as instantiating it directly in code with the `new` keyword.

Don't know anymore what the solution for my custom cell problem was. Hope this helps.